# How import png image from directory as nodes using nested for loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, conversion, foreach, standalone, png

Is it possible to generate separate and edited png files from a directory using a (nested) for loop? I have a directory of png files and I want to annotate each one individually and then export them as png files with the annotation. I just simply want to annotate with a number or a letter. This is what I tried so far, but it does not do what I desire.

```
\documentclass[border=1,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=2pt] (origin) at (0,0) {};
\foreach \x in {2,...,5,A,B,C,D,E}{
    \foreach \i in {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20}{

    \node[inner sep=2pt,right=\i of origin] {\includegraphics[scale=.2] {./\x image.png} node[above] {\x}};
    }
}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You've put them all in the same picture. Is that what you want? You need a separate node for the label either a new `\node` or a `label`. Writing `node` in a node will produce a node containing the text `node`.

Comment: Actually no, I don't want them all in the same picture, but that was the limit of my knowledge. I wanted to see first whether the for loop was working.

Comment: So what are you asking? Which step are you on? What do you want from an answer to this question exactly?

Comment: Also, you are including each image many times with different labels, so every image gets every label once. Is that needed?

Comment: I would like to import each png image separately, then annotate it, then export it to a directory with that annotation in png format

Comment: I didn't plan for each image to get every label, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code puts an annotation below each of the three sample images, `example-image-a`, `example-image-b` and `example-image-c` and exports each image-with-annotation to `<jobname-n>.png` where `n` takes the values 0, 1 and 2.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt,tikz,convert]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {a,b,c}
{%
  \tikz{\node [inner sep=0pt, label=below:Image \j: example-image-\i] {\includegraphics{example-image-\i}}; }%
}
\end{document}
```

You don't need the `count` unless you want to use it. I just wanted to put something in the annotations.